# Median of symmetric distribution, where median is defined using inverse of CDF

Tags: probability, statistics, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X$ be a symmetric random variable, that is $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution function $F$. Suppose that $F$ is continuous and strictly increasing in a neighborhood of $0$. Then prove that the median $m$ of $F$ is equal to $0$, where we define $m:=\inf\{x\in \mathbb{R}|F(x)\ge \frac{1}{2}\}$.

This definition of the median kind of annoys me. I could easily show that $\mathbb{P}(X\le 0)\ge \frac{1}{2}$ and $\mathbb{P}(X\ge 0)\ge \frac{1}{2}$ and by the usual definition of the median I would be done, but I don't know how to deal with that $\inf$. I could only observe that my first equality implies that $m<0$. I think that the point of the qustion is to use that $F$ is invertible on that neighborhood, but I can't make any progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know how to prove that $P(X\le 0)=1/2$, then you can prove that $0$ satisfies the "inf" definition of median by contradiction. If you assume that $\textrm{inf}\, \{x, F(x)\ge 1/2\}>0$ then, by definition of infimum, there will be some $x_0>0$ such that $F(x_0)=P(X\le x_0)<1/2$. But then $P(X\le 0)\le P(X\le x_0)<1/2$, contradicting the fact that $P(X\le 0)=1/2$. A similar contradiction arises if you assume that the infimum is negative. So it has to be zero.

Comment: thank you, but how should I prove that $\mathbb{P}(X\le 0)=\frac{1}{2}$? I think that here I have to use the continuity condition, but I am not sure how.

Comment: You mentioned that you can prove $P(x\le 0)\ge 1/2$ and $P(x\ge 0)\ge 1/2$. These two numbers add up to $1$ and are both $\ge 1/2$ so they have to be equal to $1/2$ both of them. Yes, you need continuity to make sure that $x=0$ is not an atom, so it does not contribute to the total probability.

Comment: Why do they add up to $1$? This would be true I think only if $\mathbb{P}(X=0)=0$, but I don't have that.

Comment: Continuity of $F$ at zero guarantees that.

Comment: I had a hunch that would be the case, but I can't really prove it, could you help me please?

Comment: $P(X=0)=lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}P(-\varepsilon<X<\varepsilon)$ and $P(-\varepsilon<X<\varepsilon)=F(\varepsilon)-F(-\varepsilon)\to 0$ by continuity, as $\varepsilon\to 0$.

Comment: ah, I see. And here we also used the symmetry of $X$, right?

Comment: Not really. Just continuity. You need the symmetry to prove that $P(X\le 0)=1/2$.

Comment: I think I got it now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: sorry to ask another stupid question, but why exactly can we write $P(X=0)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}P(-\varepsilon<X<\varepsilon)
$ due to continuity? It is clear to me this is true, but I can't really give a rigorous explanation.

Comment: "A similar contradiction arises..." This is incorrect; the case that the infimum is negative is not handled similarly to the case that the infimum is positive.

Comment: I would say it is very similar. If the infimum is negative, there is some $x_0<0$ such that $F(x_0)\ge 1/2$, that is $P(X\le x_0)\ge 1/2$. Since it is known that $P(X\ge 0)\ge 1/2$, it follows that $P(x_0<X\le 0)=0$ so $F$ is constant to the left of $x=0$, contradicting the assumption that it is (strictly) increasing.

Comment: @JustAnAmateur This is a general property of measures. The sequence of sets $(-\varepsilon, +\varepsilon)$ is a nested sequence shrinking to $\{0\}$. Any positive measure $P$ has the following property: If $A_{I+1}\subset A_i$ then $P(\bigcap_i A_i)=\lim_{I\to\infty}P(A_i)$

Comment: @GReyes ah, I see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Define $M:=\{x\in {\mathbb R}\mid F(x)\ge\frac12\}$. You've shown that $0\in M$. It remains to show that no number less than zero is a member of $M$. To do this:

0. You've already shown $P(X\le0)\ge\frac12$.
1. Since $F$ is continuous at $x=0$, you know $P(X=0)=0$; otherwise there would be a jump discontinuity in $F$ at $x=0$.
2. Since $F$ is strictly increasing in a neighborhood of $0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $F(t_1)<F(t_2)$ whenever $-\delta<t_1<t_2<\delta$.
3. If $t\in(-\delta, 0)$ then $-\delta<t<0<\delta$ so $$F(t)\stackrel{(2)}<F(0)=P(X\le 0)\stackrel{(1)}=P(X<0)=1-P(X\ge0)\stackrel{(0)}\le \frac12.$$ Hence $F(t)<\frac12$ and $t$ cannot be a member of $M$.
4. If $t\in (-\infty, -\delta]$, then $t\le -\delta<-\delta/2<0$ so $F(t)\le F(-\delta/2)\stackrel{(3)}<\frac12$ and again $t\not\in M$.

---

Note that **you need to use the condition** that $F$ is strictly increasing in a neighborhood of zero. If $F$ is flat in a neighborhood of zero, then $\inf M$ will be negative.